# Get Value of XML/XMP tag in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmp

I have this XMP string $xml:

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
      <xmp:CreatorTool>Microsoft Photo Gallery 16.4.3528.331</xmp:CreatorTool>
      <xmp:Rating>2</xmp:Rating>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:MP="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/">
      <MP:RegionInfo>
        <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
          <MPRI:Regions xmlns:MPRI="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/RegionInfo#">
            <rdf:Bag xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
              <rdf:li>
                <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                  <MPReg:Rectangle xmlns:MPReg="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#">0.144259, 0.358824, 0.065751, 0.098529</MPReg:Rectangle>
                </rdf:Description>
              </rdf:li>
              <rdf:li>
                <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                  <MPReg:Rectangle xmlns:MPReg="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#">0.211973, 0.294118, 0.023553, 0.035294</MPReg:Rectangle>
                </rdf:Description>
              </rdf:li>
              <rdf:li>
                <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                  <MPReg:Rectangle xmlns:MPReg="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#">0.350343, 0.423529, 0.056919, 0.085294</MPReg:Rectangle>
                  <MPReg:PersonDisplayName xmlns:MPReg="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#">xc</MPReg:PersonDisplayName>
                </rdf:Description>
              </rdf:li>
              <rdf:li>
                <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                  <MPReg:Rectangle xmlns:MPReg="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#">0.352306, 0.300000, 0.023553, 0.035294</MPReg:Rectangle>
                </rdf:Description>
              </rdf:li>
              <rdf:li>
                <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                  <MPReg:Rectangle xmlns:MPReg="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#">0.395486, 0.304412, 0.047105, 0.070588</MPReg:Rectangle>
                </rdf:Description>
              </rdf:li>
              <rdf:li>
                <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                  <MPReg:Rectangle xmlns:MPReg="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#">0.823356, 0.560294, 0.095191, 0.142647</MPReg:Rectangle>
                </rdf:Description>
              </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
          </MPRI:Regions>
        </rdf:Description>
      </MP:RegionInfo>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description xmlns:MicrosoftPhoto="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.0/">
      <MicrosoftPhoto:Rating>25</MicrosoftPhoto:Rating>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
      <dc:title>
        <rdf:Alt xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
          <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">edgf</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
      </dc:title>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
      <dc:description>
        <rdf:Alt xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
          <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">edgf</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
      </dc:description>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

I am intrested in 2 tags: MPReg:Rectangle and MPReg:PersonDisplayName.
I want to read the Rectangle value only if there is a PersonDisplayname in the same tag.

I tried converting the XMP to an array using this code:

```
function get_xmp_array( &$xmp_raw ) {
            $xmp_arr = array();
            foreach ( array(
                    'RectangleCoords' => '<MPReg:Rectangle[^>]+?xmlns:MPReg="([^"]*)"',
                    'attempt2' => '<MPReg:Rectangle>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/MPReg:Rectangle>'
            ) as $key => $regex ) {

                    // get a single text string
                    $xmp_arr[$key] = preg_match( "/$regex/is", $xmp_raw, $match ) ? $match[1] : '';

                    // if string contains a list, then re-assign the variable as an array with the list elements
                    $xmp_arr[$key] = preg_match_all( "/<rdf:li[^>]*>([^>]*)<\/rdf:li>/is", $xmp_arr[$key], $match ) ? $match[1] : $xmp_arr[$key];

                    // hierarchical keywords need to be split into a third dimension
                    if ( ! empty( $xmp_arr[$key] ) && $key == 'Hierarchical Keywords' ) {
                            foreach ( $xmp_arr[$key] as $li => $val ) $xmp_arr[$key][$li] = explode( '|', $val );
                            unset ( $li, $val );
                    }
            }
            return $xmp_arr;
    }
```

But it did not work, it returned this:

```
'RectangleCoords' => string 'http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#'
'attempt2' => string ''
```

I tried multiple functions like:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

This function only returned the first match, I dunno how to get all the matches.

I also tried this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$result = $doc->getElementsByTagName('MPReg:Rectangle');
var_dump( $result );
```

But it returned nothing:

```
object(DOMNodeList)[3]
```

I would really appreciate your help on this one.

Thank you

Comment: [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php) would be the _proper_ way to get those _namespaced_ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use Regular Expression to parse XML. Use an XML parser (DOM) and Xpath. Xpath is an expression language to select nodes of a DOM.

First create a DOM document, load the XML and create an Xpath instance for the document.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
```

The XML uses namespaces, so now you have to register prefixes aliases for them. The alias in the XML is only valid for the document. At parse time the DOM resolves the namespaces. You can read the root node as `{adobe:ns:meta/}:xmpmeta`.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'adobe:ns:meta/');
$xpath->registerNamespace('xmp', 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/');
$xpath->registerNamespace('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
$xpath->registerNamespace('MP', 'http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/');
$xpath->registerNamespace('MPRI', 'http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/RegionInfo#');
$xpath->registerNamespace('MPReg', 'http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/t/Region#');
```

This allows the Xpath instance to resolve namespaces. The expression `/x:xmpmeta` can be resolved to `/{adobe:ns:meta/}:xmpmeta` and match the root node, even if the namespace prefix/alias was different.

Now you can use `DOMXpath::evaluate()` to fetch nodes and values:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//MPRI:Regions//rdf:Description') as $description) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'rectangle' => $xpath->evaluate('string(MPReg:Rectangle)', $description),
      'person' => $xpath->evaluate('string(MPReg:PersonDisplayName)', $description),
    ]
  );
}
```

The expression `//MPRI:Regions//rdf:Description` fetches all rdf description elements inside a mpri regions element node. For each description the two expression fetch the rectangle (`string(MPReg:Rectangle)`) and the person display name (`string(MPReg:PersonDisplayName)`) as string.

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["rectangle"]=>
  string(38) "0.144259, 0.358824, 0.065751, 0.098529"
  ["person"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(2) {
  ["rectangle"]=>
  string(38) "0.211973, 0.294118, 0.023553, 0.035294"
  ["person"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(2) {
  ["rectangle"]=>
  string(38) "0.350343, 0.423529, 0.056919, 0.085294"
  ["person"]=>
  string(2) "xc"
}
array(2) {
  ["rectangle"]=>
  string(38) "0.352306, 0.300000, 0.023553, 0.035294"
  ["person"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(2) {
  ["rectangle"]=>
  string(38) "0.395486, 0.304412, 0.047105, 0.070588"
  ["person"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(2) {
  ["rectangle"]=>
  string(38) "0.823356, 0.560294, 0.095191, 0.142647"
  ["person"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I ended up using:

```
//This function will return the value of a certain tag
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname, $offset) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset);
    return $matches;
}

//Initiate variables
$People = array(array("Rectangle" => null, "PersonName" => null)); //will store the people tag informations
$coords = array(); //will store all of the offset values
$ofs = 0; //it willl temporarily store  the offset value
$i = 0; //number of results counter
$name=""; // it willl temporarily store the person's name

//It will search the XMP String for the first Rectangle result,
//Then, it will search again, but this time it will search right after the first result
//Hence the use of the offset variable, it will repeat til there is no more rectangle results
do
{
$result = getTextBetweenTags($xml, "MPReg:Rectangle", $ofs);
if( $result ) $ofs = $result[1][1]; else break;
$coords[$i] = $ofs;
$People[$i]["Rectangle"] = $result[1][0];
$i++;
}
while ( $result );

//If there is a Person name it will follow the Rectangle tag
//By that logic, and using the previous variable,
//A reverse search for the Person name will be performed
for ( $j = $i-1 ; $j >= 0 ; $j--)
{   
$result = getTextBetweenTags($xml, "MPReg:PersonDisplayName", $coords[$j]);
if( $result )
    if ($name != $result[1][0])//If the name is not the same as the previous one
    {
        $name = $result[1][0];
        $People[$j]["PersonName"] = $result[1][0];
    }
}

var_dump( $People );
```