# how to get Description metadata of an image?

Tags: php, exif

I need to get `Description` metadata of an image

```
$exif = exif_read_data('img.jpg', 0, true);
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
```

**result:**

```
FILE.FileName: img.jpg<br />
FILE.FileDateTime: 1657032928<br />
FILE.FileSize: 89183<br />
FILE.FileType: 2<br />
FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg<br />
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, GPS<br />
COMPUTED.html: width="576" height="680"<br />
COMPUTED.Height: 680<br />
COMPUTED.Width: 576<br />
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1<br />
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 0<br />
IFD0.Orientation: 1<br />
IFD0.XResolution: 300/1<br />
IFD0.YResolution: 300/1<br />
IFD0.ResolutionUnit: 2<br />
IFD0.Software: GIMP 2.10.32<br />
IFD0.DateTime: 2022:07:05 16:54:23<br />
IFD0.GPS_IFD_Pointer: 148<br />
GPS.GPSAltitude: 0/100<br />
```

there is no `Description` metadata (the data is clearly visible inside GIMP, for example)

so how can I get `Description` metadata of an image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Different formats

(Without any link to the file you tested, I assume that...)

The reason is that [Exif (Exchangeable image file format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) is not the only metadata format **and** that it does not know any item for descriptions. Most likely, because it is primarily inserted by cameras, not programs. There are other metadata formats:

- [IPTC (International Press Telecommunications Council)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC_Information_Interchange_Model):
   record `2` ("application"), [dataset `120` ("Caption/Abstract](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/IPTC.html#ApplicationRecord): *A textual description of the objectdata, particularly used where the object is not text.*")
- [XMP (Extensible_Metadata_Platform)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform):
   a `description` element in any namespace, mostly `<dc:description>`
- [RIFF (Resource Interchange File Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format#Use_of_the_INFO_chunk):
   `INFO` chunk, but [without any "description" item](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/RIFF.html#Info)
- [QTFF (QuickTime File Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format):
   list atoms [`©des`, `desc`, `ldes`, `sdes`, `dscp`, or key atom `com.apple.quicktime.description`](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html)

## Files versus metadata

Which meta formats can be expected in which file formats?

| File formats \ Metadata formats | Exif | IPTC | XMP | RIFF | QTFF | proprietary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JFIF/JPEG | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |  |  | comment |
| TIFF, CR2, ORF, DNG, RAW, JPEG-XR, NIFF, MDI | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |  |  | many |
| PNG, JNG, MNG | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |  |  | free text |
| GIF |  |  | ✓ |  |  | comment |
| WebP | ✓ |  | ✓ | ✓ |  | many |
| JPEG2000, JPEG-XL, HEIF | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |  | ✓ | many |
| PSD | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |  |  | caption |

## Finding description in multiple metadata formats in JFIFile

PHP can by default parse Exif and IPTC and XML (XMP's format), along with JFIFiles. Combining all this we can find a JFIF's description either in IPTC or XMP metadata, should it be there. Technically descriptions can occur more than once per metadata, and (of course) all of those can differ.

```php
<?php
    // Don't let the browser interpret this as HTML
    header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' );


    // Add finding to overall array and take note of metadata format in which it was found
    function found( &$aFound, $sText, $sMeta ) {
        if( !isset( $aFound[$sText] ) ) {  // Text is new?
            $aFound[$sText]= $sMeta; 
        } else {
            $aFound[$sText].= ', '. $sMeta;  // Text is known already, just add metadata format
        }
    }


    // Store all findings: key=text, value=metadata format(s)
    $aFound= array();

    // Parse picture, only JFIF/JPEG picture is supported for metadata
    getimagesize( 'C:/mypic.jpg', $aMeta );

    // Any metadata found at all?
    if( is_array( $aMeta ) )
    foreach( $aMeta as $sType=> $sData ) {
        switch( $sType ) {
            case 'APP13':  // IPTC
                $aIptc= iptcparse( $sData );
                if( is_array( $aIptc ) ) {  // Might have failed
                    if( isset( $aIptc['2#120'] ) ) {
                        // In theory tags can occur multiple times
                        foreach( $aIptc['2#120'] as $sDesc ) {
                            found( $aFound, $sDesc, 'IPTC' );
                        }
                    }
                }
            break;

            case 'APP1':  // Mostly XMP, but can also be Exif
                $iStart= strpos( $sData, '<x:xmpmeta' );
                $iEnd= strpos( $sData, '</x:xmpmeta>', $iStart+ 10 );
                if( $iStart> 0&& $iEnd> 0 ) {  // Valid XMP
                    $sData= substr( $sData, $iStart, $iEnd- $iStart+ 12 );

                    $oDom= new DOMDocument();
                    $oDom-> loadXml( $sData );  // Parse XML data
                    $oXpath= new DOMXpath( $oDom );
                    $oXpath-> registerNamespace( 'rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' );  // Resource Description Framework
                    $oXpath-> registerNamespace( 'dc', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' );  // Dublin Core

                    // First the document/file itself, then in its context the picture related info
                    foreach( $oXpath-> evaluate( '//rdf:Description//dc:description' ) as $oElem ) {
                        if( $oElem-> nodeValue ) found( $aFound, $oElem-> nodeValue, 'XMP' ); else
                        if( $oElem-> textContent ) found( $aFound, $oElem-> textContent, 'XMP' );
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }


    // Which texts have we found?
    print_r( $aFound );
```

## Related questions/answers

- [read XMP description field with php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925148/4299358) (actually reading IPTC)
- [Get Value of XML/XMP tag in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31264568/4299358) (parsing XML of XMP instead of using regular expressions)